# easy way to repeatedly grep constant text from memory

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete, grep

Simple question - I have an autocomplete bar on a webpage that autocompletes through a very large text list (say 100MB) and then calls MySQL based on the result the person picks.  Obviously with autocomplete bars I want it to be responsive and give results very rapidly 100ms type of search time).

It's too large of a list to use php strpos and MySQL isn't fast enough even with buffer pool warm up.  The solution I'm using right now is that php calls grep on the server and it works great... except this won't scale due to RAM limitations: each additional call to grep will allocate new memory when we're in fact searching the same file.

Isn't this a common problem?  Isn't there some simple program that already exists where you can just leave it running, it keeps the file in memory, and you grep from the same area in memory?  Kind of like an exceedingly simple database?

Comment: You need to clarify what you want, you say RAM doesn't scale well in one paragraph but you want to keep it in memory in the next paragraph.

Comment: Sorry - I mean that it won't scale well because each new call to grep that is concurrent will not use the memory allocated by the existing grep instances.

Comment: A database seems the most sensible solution. MySQL even has memory tables so that would more or less do what you want: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Comment: just built the memory table you suggested and it's really far far too slow... 200ms per search.  grep is much faster once the file is in cache.  There really has to be a better solution for a problem like this.

Comment: What does the table structure look like? The right indices can change a lot.

Comment: for the table I put into memory I deleted all columns and just kept (id, text to search (varchar 250)).  Have you ever used lucene or sphinx?  They might be useful here?  http://jayant7k.blogspot.com/2006/06/benchmarking-results-of-mysql-lucene.html seems to show huge performance gains

Comment: Did your test table used the correct indexes?

Comment: yes - what I didn't do though was use myisam.  I switched to myisam and indexed the text to search and it's twice as fast... still not ideal speeds, but much better than before.  Maximum query time on InnoDB was as high as 400ms, now down to 100ms, which isn't bad at all.  Do you think it's still worth exploring alternative solutions?

Comment: I just installed Solr/Lucene and this is what I'm going to use.  It is exactly what I was looking for and it is freaking incredible.  Thank you all very much for your help.